# Set JPanel to same size as the JTable it encloses

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JTable contained in a JScrollPane contained in a JPanel which is contained in a JFrame. I used the NetBeans GUI builder, so some of the auto generated code is hidden below.

In `PanelWithTable.java`:

```
public class PanelWithTable extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public PanelWithTable() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public JTable getTable() {
        return jTable1;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(jTable1.getWidth(), jTable1.getHeight());
    }
    ...
    //Generated code
    ...
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
}
```

In `OuterFrame.java`:

```
public class OuterFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public OuterFrame() {
        initComponents();
        panelWithTable1.getTable().setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        for (int i = 0, n = panelWithTable1.getTable().getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i < n; i++) {
            panelWithTable1.getTable().getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(16);
        }
        pack();
    }

    public PanelWithTable getPanelWithTable() {
        return panelWithTable1;
    }
    ...
    //Generated code
    ...
    private main.PanelWithTable panelWithTable1;
}
```

If I don't override `getPreferredSize()` it looks like this:

[image]

I want the JPanel to be the same size as the JTable so it doesn't show the border. When overriding `getPreferredSize()` it looks like this:

[image]

It's slightly smaller than the table and it cuts off the last row and column. How can I correctly get the JPanel to be the same size as the JTable?

Comment: since you are using netbeans easily you can drag jtable to the corners of jpanel. Netbeans will handle rest of the stuffs

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne But in my application the table can be different sizes, so the size needs to be based on the rows and columns of the table.

Comment: Try my suggestion and look the generated code there. SO you can modify it the way you want.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne Thanks, after trying this it now works.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne If you make your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I put my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using netbeans easily you can drag `jtable` to the corners of `jpanel`. Netbeans will handle rest of the stuffs. Try this suggestion and look the generated code there. Then you can modify it the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

1. (`JTable` inside `JScrollPane`)

   set `PreferredScrollableViewportSize` for `JTable` and to change default `FlowLayout` for `JPanel` to `GridBagLayout` (set fill to `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL`) or eventually to use `BorderLayout`, put `JScrollPane` to `CENTER` area
2. (`JTable` placed into `JPanel`)

   to change default `FlowLayout` for `JPanel` to `GridBagLayout` (set fill to `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL`) or eventually to use `BorderLayout`, put `JTable` to `CENTER` area
3. for better help sooner post an `SSCCE`/`MCVE`, short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 1):

> I have a JTable contained in a JPanel which is contained in a JFrame.

- `JTable` should be added in `JScrollPane`
- then add `JScrollPane` in `JPanel`
- and finally add `JPanel` in `JFrame`

**Note:** If you are using proper layout manger then there is no need to set the preferred size. component is by default adjust in the scroll pane.

For more info have a look at *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

sample code:

```
JTable table=new JTable();
JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(table);

JPanel panel=new JPanel();
panel.add(scrollPane);

frame.add(panel);
```

Comment: The JTable is contained in the JScrollPane, I edited my question.